# Реализация удаления и редактирования записей

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. В процессе разработки возник такой вопрос: как реализовать редактирование и удаление записей. Например? из БД выводятся записи в виде таблицы

```
<table>
<thead>    
    <tr>
        <td><b>Категория</b></td>
        <td><b>Сумма</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Операции</b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Хозтовары </td>
        <td>-280 руб.</td>
        <td>
            <button id="edit" type="button">Редактировать</button> 
            <button id="del" type="button">Удалить</button>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Продукты </td>
        <td>-888 руб.</td>
        <td>
            <button id="edit" type="button">Редактировать</button> 
            <button id="del" type="button">Удалить</button>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Рядом с каждой записью кнопки редактирования и удаления. Хочется делать всё Ajax'ом, но не могу понять как передать серверу id записи.

При нажатии кнопки должно выпадать модальное окно с полями для редактирования, заполненными данными принадлежащими редактируемой записи.

Если привязать обработчик, как обработчику понять, к какой записи относится нажатая кнопка редактирования или удаления?

Comment: Можно кадой кнопке "редактировать" запилить нечто вроде data-dbid, когда выводишь это из бд. Ну а дальше понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К кнопкам редактирования и удаления добавить data-атрибут, в котором будет содержаться id записи в базе. При клике по кнопке, например, удаления:

```
$('#del').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.post(
        'server.php',
        {'id': id},
        function(data) {
            /* На сервере удаляете запись из базы с данным id, а тут, в случае успешного удаления, удаляете запись из DOM */
        }
    );
});
```